# Get bound listbox selected values

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, databound

I thought it is easy but it's not

I have windows form with bound listbox (with value member and display member)

I enabled multiselect for the listbox

so I need to get all and only the selected values of the selected items (remember it's bound so i need the selected values not text or selected text)

so i can insert these values in some other tables

i tried this but it doesn't work

```
 for (int x = 0; x <= listProjects.SelectedItems.Count; x++)
 {
     if(listProjects.GetSelected(x) == true)
     {
         string d = listProjects.SelectedValue.ToString();
         string s = listProjects.SelectedItems[x].ToString();

         //listProjects.DisplayMember[x].ToString();
         //listProjects.Items[x].ToString();
     }
  }
```

Comment: What about the `DataSource`? We need some info on the `DataSource` of your `ListBox`

Answer (score 1):

When you bind items to a ListBox, ListBox.Items would be of the type of items you bound to it so if supposedly your items are of type BoundItemType and Value is a property of BoundItemType you can do Something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= listProjects.SelectedItems.Count; x++)
{
    BoundItemType boundItem = listProjects.SelectedItems[x] as BoundItemType;
    string selectedValue = boundItem.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `DataSource` has element type as `ItemType`, and the value member is `ItemValue`, we can cast each selected items (of `object`) to that type and get the value you want:

```
var values = listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<ItemType>()
                                   .Select(item=>item.ItemValue).ToList();
```

You can always use `Reflection` without knowledge about the underlying item type beforehand, just to be sure the `ValueMember` is valid. **However, I think this is just for reference, not recommended**:

```
var values = listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<object>()
                     .Select(item=> item.GetType()
                                        .GetProperty(listBox1.ValueMember)
                                        .GetValue(item, null)).ToList();
```